# Populate text box according to select dropdown value

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my html code :

```
<select name="plot_no" id="plot_no" class="dropdown validate_B" >
          <option value="">Select no. of Plots to book</option>
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
          <option value="4">4</option>
 </select>
        <img src="./images/rightmarked.gif" title=" mandetory"> </div>
      <div class="marginbtm5">

          <div id="divplot1" style="display:block;">
            <select name="plot_no1" id="plot_no1" >
              <option value="">Plot No.</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div id="divplot2" style="display:none;">
            <select name="plot_no2" id="plot_no2" >
              <option value="">Plot No.</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div id="divplot3" style="display:none; ">
            <select name="plot_no3" id="plot_no3" >
              <option value="">Plot No.</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div id="divplot4" style="display:none;">
            <select name="plot_no4" id="plot_no4" >
              <option value="">Plot No.</option>
            </select>
          </div>
```

here is my javascript

```
$("#plot_no").change(function(e)
{
    var id=$(this).val();

    if (id==2){
        document.getElementById("divplot2").style.display="";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("divplot2").style.display="none";    
    }


    if (id==3){
        document.getElementById("divplot2").style.display="";
        document.getElementById("divplot3").style.display="";   
    } else {
        document.getElementById("divplot2").style.display="none"; 
        document.getElementById("divplot3").style.display="none";    
    }
    if (id==4){
        document.getElementById("divplot2").style.display="";
        document.getElementById("divplot3").style.display="";
        document.getElementById("divplot4").style.display="";   
   } else {
        document.getElementById("divplot2").style.display="none"; 
        document.getElementById("divplot3").style.display="none";  
        document.getElementById("divplot4").style.display="none";  
   }

});
```

I want to show 1 dropdown, if user select 1 from above dropdown and 2 dropdowns if user   select 2 from above dropdown and resp.. So can anyone tell me about this???

Comment: are you using jQuery or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this fiddle. Added a class `plotno` for the select boxes,

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3THXE/)

Comment: This is what you needed?

Comment: this what i needed but it's not working for may be jquery conflicts..i included 1.11.0

Answer (score 0):

Check this **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/shaun1ak/5wKas/)**

```
$("#plot_no").change(function(e)
{
    var id=$(this).val();
    console.log(id);
    if (id =='2'){
        $('#divplot2').show();
    }
    if (id=='3'){
        $('#divplot2,#divplot3').show();
    }
    if (id=='4'){
        $('#divplot2,#divplot3,#divplot4').show();
    }

});
```

`if (id==2){}` won't work. `.val()` returns a string.